# Raising UAC window loads my form twice

Tags: vb.net

I am using following code to raise UAC window.  It works fine but my form that contains button to raise this window is shown twice.  I mean if I put it in CopyFiile Button, when I click this button, it raises UAC windows, copies file, gives success message and then opens another instance of the same form that contains copyfile button.  Please help.

```
 Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo
    proc.UseShellExecute = True
    proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath
    proc.Verb = "runas"
    Try
        Process.Start(proc)
    Catch
        ' The user refused to allow privileges elevation.
        MsgBox("Permission denied by user ! Can not proceed.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        vrIfDenied = 1
        Return
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but i see your `proc` filename property is equals to it's self. You are running the same application and makes 2 instances of the current application

Comment: you mean  proc.Verb = "runas"  I just picked this code from Microsoft's site.  Please correct me what to do.

Comment: no i mean proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath means that the file name to run is the same with the current running application so this make 2 instance of the application. i think you must close the "UnRaised form"

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Let me try this.  I come back to you.

Comment: `Me.Dispose only Disposes of the resources (other than memory) used by the Form.` - MSDN. it does not close the form at all... you should use `Me.Close`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
<DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint:="IsUserAnAdmin")> _
Public Shared Function IsUserAnAdmin() As Boolean
End Function
```

Now when your app loads, check to see if it is running as elevated priviledges, and grey out the Copyfile button like this if it isn't:

```
If IsUserAnAdmin() = False Then
   btnCopyFile.enabled=false
ElseIf IsUserAnAdmin() = True Then
   btnCopyFile.enable=true
   btnElevateMe.enabled=false
End If
```

Now you can add a 2nd button (btnElevateMe) which will use the code you originally posted to elevate the priviledges and bring up the UAC prompt.  When running WITH priviledges, it will be greyed out.

Also, add to your code after "End Try" this:

```
Application.Exit()
```

And it will close the app after starting a second instance with elevated priviledges.